# How to fix this query in MongoDB?

Tags: linux, database, mongodb

```js
db.inspections.update(
  { "id": "20032-2020-ACME" }:
  { $set:
    {
      "business_name": "NEW ACME Flowers",
      "result: business re-opened",
      "comments": "Flowers after the explosion"
    }
  }
)
```

I keep getting the error that there is a missing parenthesis, but when I add one I get an error that a property name is expected but there is a '}'.

Comment: remove the : from { "id": "20032-2020-ACME" }:   <-----this one make it ,

Comment: Now it says there is a : missing after property id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (but those are not question to ask, they are just small typing mistakes that we all do, : was wrong and you forgot the "")

```js
db.collection.update({
  "id": "20032-2020-ACME"
},
{
  $set: {
    "business_name": "NEW ACME Flowers",
    "result": "business re-opened",
    "comments": "Flowers after the explosion"
  }
})
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.